# creating a ramfs or using /dev/shm without root privileges in >=android 4.0

Tags: root-access, ram

My goal is to create a ramfs for the python application I am developing. On *nix this is fairly easy and currently working.

1. I really want to have a ramfs, as those get not swapped out to
   disk, when memory fills up.
2. I need to have this ramfs created without root access, as I can not
   expect all users of my app to root their device.

So far, I can only create a ramfs/tmpfs as root. To circumvent this restriction, I though I could use /dev/shm, create a directory there and chmod/chown it, but my test-android has no /dev/shm but /dev/ashmem, which does not work as I expected:

```
#cd /dev/ashmem
sh: cd: /dev/ashmem - not a directory
```

So I can't mkdir, chown, chmod at all. I can under *nix.

Also using tmpfs (which /dev/ashmem supposedly is), files will get swapped out. This is not what I want.

How can I get my application to work with android under **the constraint that the used location in memory will never get swapped and is mountable without root privileges?**

I need:

- a user mounted ramfs (or ramfs-analog)
- must not be swapped under any circumstances
- needs to support standard filesystem tools like chmod,chown,mkdir,tar

alternativly, (as i am fairly newbish regarding android) is there **a way to get root access for editing a fstab-like file** in android so I can be onetime-root during install, make the edit and mount as user after the installation process?

I am using python with rapt to package my application to .apk, if this info is helping here.

Comment: AFAIK it's impossible without root, and you must do it every time you reboot.

Comment: Definitely not possible.